# Fill a polygon using Core Graphics in Swift

Tags: swift, core-graphics, polygon, fill

The goal is to fill a polygon using Core Graphics in Swift.

The following code does just that if all of the endpoints are known.

```
   func drawPolySegment() {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 512, height: 512))

        let img = renderer.image { ctx in

            let endpoints = [
                CGPoint(x: 200, y: 175),
                CGPoint(x: 270, y: 170),
                CGPoint(x: 300, y: 100)
            ]

            ctx.cgContext.addLines(between: endpoints)

            UIColor.yellow.setFill()
            ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
        }
        imageView.image = img
    }
```

However, the endpoints for the desired shape are not easily obtainable and so a more generic approach was opted for using rotate(by:), move(to:), addline(to:), translate(by:) methods as follows:

```
    func drawPolygon() {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 512, height: 512))

        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            let apexes: CGFloat = 3   //5     //6
            let length: CGFloat = 500 //190   //140
            let angle: CGFloat = 2 * π / apexes
            let zero: CGFloat = 0

            UIColor.brown.setStroke()
            UIColor.yellow.setFill()
            ctx.cgContext.setLineWidth(10)
            ctx.cgContext.setLineCap(.round)

            ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 256, y: 5)

            for segment in 0..<Int(apexes * 2) {
                if segment == 0 {
                    ctx.cgContext.rotate(by: angle)
                } else if segment % 2 == 0 {
                    ctx.cgContext.rotate(by: 2 * angle)
                } else {
                    ctx.cgContext.rotate(by: -angle)
                }
                ctx.cgContext.move(to: CGPoint(x: zero, y: zero))
                ctx.cgContext.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: length, y: zero))
                ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: length, y: zero)
            }

            ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
        }

        imageView.image = img
    }
```

The code above generates a beautifully outlined shape, but will not fill with colour.  The values commented out for "apexes" and "length" are valid for the 512 x 512 rendering space created.  Why does the shape fill for the first code sample and not the second?  What is missing from the second code sample to make the shape fill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't drawing a polygon, you're drawing 3 separate unconnected lines.  Each `move(to:)` starts a new polygon.

You can fix this by only doing the `move(to:)` for the first segment:

```
for segment in 0..<Int(apexes * 2) {
    if segment == 0 {
        ctx.cgContext.rotate(by: angle)
        ctx.cgContext.move(to: CGPoint(x: zero, y: zero))
    } else if segment % 2 == 0 {
        ctx.cgContext.rotate(by: 2 * angle)
    } else {
        ctx.cgContext.rotate(by: -angle)
    }

    ctx.cgContext.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: length, y: zero))
    ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: length, y: zero)
}
```

---

**Results:**

`apexes: 3, length: 500`

[image]

`apexes: 5, length: 190`

[image]

`apexes: 6, length: 140`

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  That the lines are separate explains why the rounded corners disappear when the move(to:) statement is only allowed to execute once.  I overcame this by calling the setLineJoin method with the .round case:   ```ctx.cgContext.setLineJoin(.round)``` instead of:  ```ctx.cgContext.setLineCap(.round)```

Comment: Additionally, the segments loop must be iterated one further pass in order to round the final corner.

Comment: Instead of adding an additional segment, close your path: `ctx.cgContext.closePath()`

Comment: That is much more elegant solution.

Comment: In fact, you can leave off the last segment if you are closing the path. `for segment in 0..<Int(apexes * 2 - 1)`.